# The initial data metrics is Map[String, Any], and one of the data types in Any is WrappedArray(map(),map()). How do I get a value from map

Tags: scala, bigdata

I have some metrics data like below, it's Map[String, Any], I want to get the data from Map, e.g. I want to get non_unique -> 1 from metrics data.

`Map(applicationId -> local-1673262860096,  job_name -> dist_batch,  tmst -> 1673262884352,  measure_name -> duplication_measure,  metrics -> WrappedArray( Map(metric_name -> total, metric_value -> 50),  Map(metric_name -> duplicate, metric_value -> 1),  Map(metric_name -> unique, metric_value -> 48),  Map(metric_name -> non_unique, metric_value -> 1),  Map(metric_name -> distinct, metric_value -> 49) ),  measure_type -> Duplication,  data_source -> source)`

I try to use `val metricToInvestigate= metrics.get("metrics").get`, but find that `metricToInvestigate` becomes to `Any` type, but I don't know how to get the output like `non_unique -> 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta cast it:

```
val metricsMap: Map[String, Int] = 
  metrics("metrics")
  .asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String,Int]]]
  .map { m => m("metric_name") -> m("metric_value") }
  .toMap
```